# why is codeigniter email not functional for abc@company.com.np

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter email. Everything is correct except that mail isn't sent to my client email which is something like `abc@companyname.com.np` but goes to gmail and my office mail.I have bulk email ids to send to. Have I done something wrong or is it the problem of client's company mail settings ??

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['validate'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com', 'ABCTechnologies');
$list = array($form->admin_email);
$this->email->to($list); 
$this->email->subject($form->form_title);
$message = 'You have got a new Feedback. Here are the Details : <br/>';
    '.$email_fields['message'].'<br/>';
$this->email->message($message); 
$this->email->send();
```

where `$list` is array of mail id.Any suggesstions are welcome.

I changed the smtp also but to no avail.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.sipradi.com.np';
```

and smtp port is by default 25.
Help

Comment: `abc@companyname.com.np` it does not looks like a proper email address...

Comment: @bipen xxx@sipradi.com.np what about this ???

Comment: check inside spam... the above code should work..

Comment: @bipen waiting for clien't response. I don't know why it's not working

Comment: @bipen n yess it isn't in spam. I told them to check

Comment: though there is some error in the codes you posted like escaping `'`.. but i guess that is just a typo since the other reciepents is getting the email... just make you the email address is proper....

Comment: If all but on recipient receives the email, then the problem is with the individual recipient. - could be isp spam filter, client spam filter, or they may have their email sorted backwards :\